# "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'reshape'."

Tags: python, numpy, attributeerror

```
# similarity matrix

sim_mat = np.zeros([len(cleaned_texts), len(cleaned_texts)])
for i in range(len(sentences)):
    for j in range(len(sentences)):
        if i != j:
            sim_mat[i][j] = cosine_similarity(sentence_vectors[i].reshape(1, dim),
sentence_vectors[j].reshape(1, dim))[0, 0]
sim_mat = np.round(sim_mat, 3)
# print(sim_mat)
```

This line `sentence_vectors[j].reshape(1, dim))[0, 0]` is showing an error:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost impossible to answer definitely without knowing what 'sentence_vectors', 'cleaned_text' and 'sentences' are.

I can explain the error message though. It seems that you expect *sentence_vectors* to be a list of numpy arrays, but the error tells you that *sentence_vectors[j]* is a float, not a numpy array. You should probably ensure that the list is generated correctly. :)

Comment: Is it possible to convert float to numpy array?